# How to make html table made by list responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a table with list using `ul li`. Here is my html code.

```
<div style="" class="first_calendar clendar-wrapper calendar-1">

     <ul class="calendar ">
       <li class="calen-title"><a href="#">Sunday  <br>Mar 22</a></li>               
       <li class="" style="min-height:40px;"><a data-day="7" rel="21" href="#"> 6:00 am</a> </li>
       <li class="" style="min-height:40px;"><a data-day="7" rel="22" href="#"> 6:15 am</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="calendar ">
       <li class="calen-title"><a href="#">Monday  <br>Mar 23</a></li>
       <li class="" style="min-height:40px;"><a data-day="1" rel="21" href="#"> 6:00 am</a> </li>
       <li class="" style="min-height:40px;"><a data-day="1" rel="22" href="#"> 6:15 am</a> </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="calendar ">
       <li class="calen-title"><a href="#">Tuesday  <br>Mar 24</a></li>
       <li class="" style="min-height:40px;"><a data-day="2" rel="21" href="#"> 6:00 am</a> </li>
       <li class="" style="min-height:40px;"><a data-day="2" rel="22" href="#"> 6:15 am</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my css code.

```
.calendar{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*width: 40px;*/
    list-style: none;
    float:left;

}
.clendar-wrapper{
    /*float: left;*/

    /*background-image: url("../img/table_bg.png");*/
    background-position: 0 -58px;
    /*float: left;*/
}
.clendar-wrapper{
    display: none;

    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-height:350px;   overflow-x:hidden ;   padding-bottom:10px; 
}
.table-responsive {
    width: 918px;
    /*border:1px solid red;*/
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: visible;
}


@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    .clendar-wrapper{ 
        width: 100%;
        height:auto;   
    } /* your css rules for ipad portrait */
}
@media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .clendar-wrapper{   
        /*width: 100%;*/
        height:auto;   

    } /* your css rules for ipad landscape */
}

.calendar-1{
    display: block;
}
.prev-table{
    display: none;
}

.login_register a {
    color:white;
}

.calen-title {
    background-color: #D9E8F4 !important;
}

.calen-title a{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222; 
    font-weight: bold;

}

.calendar li{
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.calendar li a {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 16px;
}



.calendar li:nth-child(2n+2) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.pagi_list .pre_btn, .pagi_list .nex_btn{
    margin: 0px;
}

.last_link, .first_link {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    color:#d65c4f;
}
```

It is coded on bootstrap. When i open it on small resolution device columns drop down. Here i have created a demo link [click here to open](http://appspartans.com/test/). Please sugggest me how can i make this calendar responsive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have css rules only for 768 x 1024 px resolution and you didn't define any rules for lower resolutions, you need to do that and try to change the way the elements are laid in lower resolutions because just specifying table width as 100% will only make it smaller but not responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using media queries, it isn't usually wise to set the height of the device, just the width. The orientation of the device sets the width, so the media query will still work if you change between portrait and landscape.

You could have the calendar wrapper 100% but a maximum of 700px, which makes each day at 100px fit inside it perfectly, then if the screen is less than 700px you could move them into a vertical arrangement. I have thrown together an example here just using one simple media query > https://jsfiddle.net/pfg1dxfy/ You will see that by grabbing the bar between the javascript window and the results window and resizing it, the tables will change based on the width.

I have also added a simple clear fix, you need this when floating elements. In the CSS it is .clear {clear:both;} and you then include it after all of the floated elements with

```
.calendar{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
}

.clendar-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 699px) {
    .calendar{
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
}
```